# how to disabled a button when press three times

Tags: php

Hi I just wanted to ask if there is a possible way when the word edit was press three times, the edit will be disable. on the image I have attach is a multivendor page, vendors can edit there products, what I wanted to achieve is when the edit was press 3x, the edit will be disabled. and ofcourse the edit button will be disabled only on product01, the product02 edit word won't be affected.

[image]

I found the edit code in php here it is:

```
<span class="edit"><a href="<?php echo dokan_edit_product_url( $post->ID ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Edit', 'dokan' ); ?></a> | </span>
```

can anyone help me? Thankyou

Comment: Or limiting the button pressed

Comment: i have found this 3 sites but I don't know how to input this into the code that I have post, these are the 3 sites I have found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841632/limit-click-button-in-html , http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/25242-limit-number-button-clicks.html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550150/how-to-rate-limit-clicks-on-a-button-to-once-per-minute-in-javascript  can anyone help to input this inside the code that I gave above or using functioncode

Comment: So you want to allow them edit their products only for 3 times and so you should do this with php. You should save the edit times in db and check it every time that page loads. If counter value >= 3 then do not call dokan_edit_product_url()

Answer (score 2):

Use Javascript, on the click event write in a new variable and count the click. If is equal with 3, then add the attribute to the button, that people can't use this.

As simple example with the help of jQuery. I think jQuery is much better, is always active in the back end of WordPress. Copy the script, change the selector to your ID or class, that you identify the right input field, in a script and load it via hook, like `load-{$page_hook}` only on the page, there you will use this script.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    var counter = 1,
        element = 'input.edit';

    $( element ).click( function(e) {
        counter ++;
        // for control debugging in console
        console.log( counter );
        if ( counter > 3 ) {
            $( element ).attr( 'disabled', true );
        }
    } )

} );
```

- See the script as working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5b1w89ev/
- Alternative you can check a demo inside the SE Sandbox: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/299351#299351

Comment: i have found this 3 sites but I don't know how to input this into the code that I have post, these are the 3 sites I have found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841632/limit-click-button-in-html , http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/25242-limit-number-button-clicks.html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550150/how-to-rate-limit-clicks-on-a-button-to-once-per-minute-in-javascript  can anyone help to input this inside the code that I gave above or using functioncode

Comment: See the enhancements. Maybe this helps you more.

Comment: Hi the enhancement is the code above right?

Comment: Hi my class name is "edit",after i copy the jquery code, how can I hook the jquery code into the classname?

Comment: switch the element `input` to your class `input.edit`, see again the changes.

Comment: It would be nice to have the [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) available here on [wordpress.se] ;-)

Comment: Hi, one last question, when I click refresh, the button can be selected again, how can I disable the button forever.

Comment: That's only possible, if you save the count, like in the database as option.